# AWS Dynamodb Storage Backend for Titan Cloudformation SSH Tunnel Not Working

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan, gremlin

I am following the instructions given here:

https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend

and here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.GremlinServerEC2.html

I am able to get through the stack deployment. I can ping the ec2 instance and also gain remote access. When I try to create the ssh tunnel as mentioned in the instructions, the connection gets established (checked using lsof -n) but I don't see a return and I can't do anything further. Seems like the mac terminal gets stuck or something. It's quite frustrating being new to backend, I am thinking of switching to OrientDB or something. Please Help. Thanks.